# Send data in a specific packet format using php sockets

Tags: php, sockets, packets

I have to send some data in the format of TCP plain packets. I have read and understood how to use sockets to send data, but I can't find any help on how to create packets in a specific format. I will appreciate some help please.

Thanks

Comment: Well depends on the format. If it is a binary format you probably want to have a look at [`pack`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) and [`unpack`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php).

Comment: I think you should use `socket_sendto` which can send to a socket -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-sendto.php, you define your protocol in the `socket_create` function.

Comment: I want to create a packet according to the following format Packet Type 2bytes, Packet Length 2 bytes, Attribute type 2 bytes, Attribute length 2 bytes, Attribute Value

Comment: @crazyghost - Just look at the manual page for format (link is given) to construct the format string. Quite simple really.

Comment: i cant find the format link Ed Heal can u pls post it here i will really appreciate it

Comment: @EdHeal I have to send the data in plain text, but using  pack() will also mean the server has to use unpack to read the data in the packet. I have no control on the server, basically I have been provided with a document which specifies how I am supposed to send the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look up [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) for creating binary packets of a paticular format.